# Why does MongoDB throw error "ns does not exist"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't understand why MongoDB triggers an error with the following NodeJS code:

```
import {
  Collection,
  Document,
  Filter,
  IndexDirection,
  MongoClient,
  ObjectId
} from "mongodb";

export const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_URL);
await client.connect();
export const database = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
await database.command({ ping: 1 });

const users = database.collection("User");
console.log({ count: await users.countDocuments() }); // prints 0

await database.command({
  collMod: "User",
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: ["_id", "email"],
      additionalProperties: false,
      properties: {
        _id: { bsonType: "objectId" },
        email: { bsonType: "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  validationLevel: "strict"
}); // triggers error
```

The last instruction triggers the following error:

```
MongoServerError: ns does not exist
```

I understand that it comes from the fact that the collection doesn't exist, but shouldn't it exist by the time `command` is called? Thanks!

Comment: Why should the collection exist unless you created it?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The doc says `database.collection("User");` creates the collection if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think so. As long as you don't insert any documents or create an index, no collection should be created.

Comment: It does say that: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/Db.html#collection
"Returns a reference to a MongoDB Collection. If it does not exist it will be created implicitly."

Comment: You can check by yourself with [db.getCollectionNames()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames)

Comment: Yes I know nor the collection nor the database is actually created. My question is why.

Comment: Do you have permissions to create the database/collection?

Comment: Yes, inserting a first document creates the collection effectively (and the db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote that `await users.countDocuments()` returns 0 as workaround, effectively what happens here is:

1. `ns not found exception` is thrown.
2. This exception is handled by returning 0 without actual exception.

You can see it in the shell as well:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> use notexisteddb
switched to db notexisteddb
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.coll.count()
0
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> show collections
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Is that expected or a bug?

Comment: expected, I saw this behavior a lot before

Comment: So, why the database.collection("User"); statement is not creating the User collection implicitly as it says in the documentation.

Comment: because it does nothing, ie it doesn't send a command to the server. Only actual operation does it. Can you point me to the documentation you're referring to?